# Junit test classes not able to find set of resource files , from test packages, though resources.srcDirs mentioned in gradle build

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I am executing a gradle build. While doing so, the tests are failing as they are not able to find the resource files in the classpath, though I've mentioned them in my sourceSets code.

my project directory structure is:

```
j2ee_configchk
--|configchk
           --------|src
                   ---|main
                       ----|java
                       ----|resources
                           ---------|META-INF
                                    --------|abc.gif
                   ---|test
                      ----|java
                      ----|java2
                      ----|resources
                          ---------|static
                                   ------|abc
                                         ---|cbe.txt
                                   ------|junits
                                         ------|bde.txt
```

Below is my build.gradle snippet:

```
 sourceSets {
            test {
                  java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java','src/test/java2']
                  print sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs 

                  sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources/', 'src/test/static/']
                  print sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs
            }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\j2ee_configchck\configchck\src\test\resources]
[C:\j2ee_configchecker\configchck\src\main\resources, C:\j2ee_configchck\configchck\src\test\static]
So many assert Errors(file not found)....
```

Still m getting AssertFailure errors which testing for junits, because Junit tests are not able to file the abc.gif,cbe.txt,bde.txt, while executing

What m I missing?

Thanks

Comment: And how are you test files trying to access these files? `new File("test/resources/...")? MyClass.class.getResource... etc?

Comment: Yeah, similar,  the file is loaded from a location which I didn't set, probably some default location : build/test/res/junit/bde.txt

Comment: You need to show the actual code you are using to load those resources, not just say 'yeah something like that'.